# How to customize footer/header in each pages?

Tags: fancyhdr

I have been working on a research paper right now. Unfortunately, I have been encountering the following problems.

**1.** I have a problem customizing the footer and header for each page. The first page must have different header and footer that's why I used the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Frob}{Frob}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{\thepage}
\lhead{\small{\textbf{Foot Note for First Page Only}}}
\lfoot{
Copyright \copyright}

\begin{document}

\date{}
\nocite{*}
\title{Title}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I cannot resize the fonts of the footer and the header. It's too big.

**2.** I need to apply different footer and headers for the remaining pages. When I use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, the footer and header for the first page only is added in the whole document. I need to only headers at the center of the even and odd pages (excluding first page).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: What is you want is not very clear. What should be the contents of those centred headers?

Comment: How to code? Odd pages (3, 5, and 7 only): title of the article is the header (center aligned) and page number at the footer (center aligned). Even pages (2, 4  & 6): header must be last name of author and page number at the footer. For the first page only: header (left aligned) must indicate a text (e.g. Journal number), and the copyright (left aligned) and page number (center aligned) at the footer.

Comment: Please clarify by editing the question. Comments are not meant for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pagestyle{fancy}` to define the first page and then use a personalized style for the whole document. You can create this personalized style with `\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}` and swift to this style in the second page with the instruction `\pagestyle{documentstyle}`. The following code should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small{\textbf{Journal Nº 1234 \copyright}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Default value: 0.4pt

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[CO]{Title of the article}
    \fancyhead[CE]{Last name of the author}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
}

\begin{document}

\section{First page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage \pagestyle{documentstyle} 

\section{Second page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage

\section{Third page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage

\section{Fourth page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage

\section{Fifth page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage

\section{Sixth page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage

\section{Seventh page}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried using the codes. But it didn't work. Is there other way of doing it without the use of the lipsum package? Thank you.

Comment: You don’t need the lipsum package, I used it only to put some blind text for the example. You can delete the `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum[1-5]` instructions. You can also delete `\usepackage{parskip}`.