# Rome and arabic footer

Tags: footer

My problem is closely related to the below question:

[Roman numerals at the bottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156109/roman-numerals-at-the-bottom)

My document should contain:

- Front page (no number)
- Title page (no number)
- Preface (i)
- Abstract (ii)
- Acknowlegdement (iii)
- Contents (iv)
- Introduction (1 of 87)
- Related work (2 of 87)
  ...
- References (87 of 87)

The difference between the link and my question is:

"87 of 87" when arabic numbers and only "iv" when rome numbers.

I can't come across a solution to this.

Do anyone have an idea of how to resolve it?

EDIT:
Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
Frontpage (no number)
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Titlepage (no number)

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
Preface (i)
\newpage
Abstract (ii)
\newpage
Acknowlegdement (iii)
\newpage
Contents (iv)

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Introduction (1 of 3)
\newpage
Related work (2 of 3)
\newpage
References (3 of 3)


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you. I have added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a solution, which can be applied in this context as well:

[How to customize footer/header in each pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432510/how-to-customize-footer-header-in-each-pages)

Here is the minimal working example, as I wanted it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
Frontpage (no number)
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Titlepage (no number)

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
Preface (i)
\newpage
Abstract (ii)
\newpage
Acknowlegdement (iii)
\newpage
Contents (iv)

\newpage \pagestyle{documentstyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Introduction (1 of 3)
\newpage
Related work (2 of 3)
\newpage
References (3 of 3)


\end{document}
```